# Jenkins stopped work on checking out revision

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson

I have problem with Jenkins bilds.

Sometimes my build hangs on operations "Checking out Revision". The problem is not constant. I can get this issue in 4-5 times of 10 bilds.

I am waiting 10-20 minutes and the abort this hangs bild.

Console log:

```
Started by upstream project "master" build number 737
originally caused by: 
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/master/workspace/CI_BUILD/integration
Checkout:integration / /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/master/workspace/CI_BUILD/integration - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@29b99c
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision e0963076406dd8bd6fcbd2d31ff37ad4ea60669a (origin/master)
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:shaliko/shaliko.git
Commencing build of Revision e0963076406dd8bd6fcbd2d31ff37ad4ea60669a (origin/master)
Checking out Revisione 0963076406dd8bd6fcbd2d31ff37ad4ea60669a (origin/master)
```

In Jenkins config:

- 6 executors
- Quiet period 10
- SCM checkout retry count 10

I update Jenkins to version 1.500 and update "Jenkins GIT plugin" to version 1.1.26 - no effect.

What I should check or update?

Comment: This could be just a network issue. Next time you notice it "hanging" try running a checkout on the Jenkins box (on a different folder obviously). If that has issues too, it's your network

Comment: I tried reproduce this issue from console on server many a time. If I do git clone or git pull it always works without problems. And I have Jenkins setting "SCM checkout retry count 10", network problem would be fix.

Comment: OK, try looking in Jenkins logs on the file system, they should be in `JENKINS_HOME\..\Tomcat 6.0\logs`. Look in catalina.log and stderr.log

Answer (score 0):

Fixed issue by updating JDK to version 7u11.

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Same issue here - And how exactly did you do that - are you on ubuntu?